# self hosting my open source program

Tags: open-source, project-hosting

Say I would like to host my open source software by myself, i.e. not in sourceforge or google code but host my own svn and issue tracker and documentation on my server.

What is the best software for doing that?

Comment: Why would you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Bruno: because sometimes is fun ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of people like [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Well you'd use [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) + [subversion server](http://subversion.tigris.org/) on your own machine.

But there is [assembla.com](http://www.assembla.com/), and also [xp-dev.com](http://www.xp-dev.com/), if you don't like the licensing forced on you by the websites you listed.

Answer (score 1):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is a nice alternative to trac.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to host with dreamhost or webfaction. They both offer hosted svn services. For documentation, you can go with mediawiki, if you want.

Note: I'm not affiliated with those 2 host, I just use dreamhost not webfaction, but from googling the net, I found out that webfaction is better than dreamhost.

Answer (score 0):

Try [BitNami](http://bitnami.org) packages for [Redmine](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine) or [Trac](http://bitnami.org/stack/trac), they are easy to use installers that you can run on your server (there are also virtual machines available as well)